# How can I scrape the results of a search after logging into a website using Python and beautifulsoup4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to log-in to a website, perform a search on a page and then scrape all the results.

I've somehow managed to log-in using Python and requests but when I do a get request on the page I want to perform search or whenever I do a post request on that page with all the search criteria being passed in the body, I'm not really getting any search result. Instead the title still says "Login to page" which is the title of the login-page, so somehow it seems I'm not able to perform any REST operation after logging in.  Is there any specific way to scrape the website when it requires one to login and then perform a search?

Following is my attempt:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

USERNAME = "abcdefgh"
PASSWORD = "xxxxxxx"

LOGIN_URL = "https://www.assortis.com/en/login.asp"
URL = "https://www.assortis.com/en/members/bsc_search.asp?act=sc"
SEARCH_URL = "https://www.assortis.com/en/members/bsc_results.asp"


def scrapeIt():
    session_requests = requests.session()
    
    #login
    result = session_requests.get(LOGIN_URL)
    tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
    # print(tree)
        
    # Create payload
    payload = {
        "login_name": USERNAME,
        "login_pwd": PASSWORD,
        "login_btn": "Login"
    }

    search_payload = {
        'mmb_cou_hid': '0,0',
        'mmb_don_hid': '0,0',
        'mmb_sct_hid': '0,0',
        'act': 'contract',
        'srch_sdate': '2016-01-01',
        'srch_edate': '2018-12-31',
        'procurement_type': 'Services',
        'srch_budgettype': 'any',
        'srch_budget': '',
        'srch_query': '',
        'srch_querytype': 'all of the words from'
    }
    # Perform login
    result = session_requests.post(LOGIN_URL, data=payload, headers=dict(referer=LOGIN_URL))

    # Scrape url
    result = session_requests.get(URL, headers=dict(referer=URL))
    result = session_requests.post(SEARCH_URL, data=search_payload, headers=dict(referer=SEARCH_URL))
    content = result.content
    # print(content)
    data = result.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

    print(soup)


scrapeIt()
```

EDIT: the webpage is possibly in JavaScript.

Comment: page may use JavaScript but request/beautifulsoup/lxml dont run JavaScript. you can open web browser, turn off JavaScript and login to your page to see what script can get.

Comment: did you check page which you get after login in script ? I think you didn't login. I opened login page and check request in DevTool in Chrome/Firefox and I see it sends login and password as `login_name` and `login_pwd`, not `username`/`password`

Comment: @furas sorry it was a typo, I tried with login_name and login_pwd...its not working. Also how to turn off java script and see a webpage?

Comment: it also send POST request to `"https://www.assortis.com/login.asp"` - without `/en/` in url.

Comment: Long time ago there was option to turn off JavaScript. Now it is easier to install some extension to have button on toolbar.

Comment: @furas I just turned off the javascript, the login page url changed. So how do I login, perform a search and then scrap the results of javascript web page?

Comment: get all information about urls, parameters which are used when JavaScript is turned off, and use this information in script. Or use module [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html) to control real web browser which will load page and run javascript. You will even see browser's window.

Comment: thing is, when i turned the java script off in my browser, the login page wasn't responding at all, even the textboxes in the login page for entering username and password where not working upon clicking :/

Comment: so this page can't work without JavaScript. So you have to use `Selenium`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your response.text to local file after you've logged in, to see if you actually logged in, check the file
otherwise instead of reverse engineering http requests, try Selenium chromedriver.

The logging part is easier on Selenium, but finding stuff on the page is not, use wait for exceptions for dynamic loading, driver.page_source to see the html, sometimes browser write html different, ie: `<tbody>` tags